# Compile error on the Microchip MCC generated code

Tags: microchip, mplab, enc28j60

I use Microchip MPLAB X MCC to generate the base application using TCP/IP lite stack for system with pic16f18346 and enc28j60 chipsets. I get the following errors. Scanning thru this error log you will find 1 fatal error with respect to udpv4.h file not found.

> ```
> mcc_generated_files/TCPIPLibrary/log_syslog.c:51:10: fatal error: 'udpv4.h' file not found
> #include "udpv4.h"
> ```

How do I go about correcting this issue?

ERROR LOG:

```
make -f nbproject/Makefile-default.mk SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf

make[1]: Entering directory 'D:/videos/mchip/enc28j60/enc28j60_app1.X'

make  -f nbproject/Makefile-default.mk 
dist/default/production/enc28j60_app1.X.production.hex

make[2]: Entering directory 'D:/videos/mchip/enc28j60/enc28j60_app1.X'

"C:\Program Files\Microchip\xc8\v2.32\bin\xc8-cc.exe"  -mcpu=16F18346 -c   -mdfp="C:/Program Files/Microchip/MPLABX/v5.45/packs/Microchip/PIC16F1xxxx_DFP/1.5.133/xc8"  -fno-short-double -fno-short-float -O0 -fasmfile -maddrqual=ignore -xassembler-with-cpp -mwarn=-3 -Wa,-a -DXPRJ_default=default  -msummary=-psect,-class,+mem,-hex,-file  -ginhx032 -Wl,--data-init -mno-keep-startup -mno-osccal -mno-resetbits -mno-save-resetbits -mno-download -mno-stackcall   -std=c99 -gdwarf-3 -mstack=compiled:auto:auto     -o build/default/production/mcc_generated_files/TCPIPLibrary/ipv4.p1 mcc_generated_files/TCPIPLibrary/ipv4.c

"C:\Program Files\Microchip\xc8\v2.32\bin\xc8-cc.exe"  -mcpu=16F18346 -c   -mdfp="C:/Program Files/Microchip/MPLABX/v5.45/packs/Microchip/PIC16F1xxxx_DFP/1.5.133/xc8"  -fno-short-double -fno-short-float -O0 -fasmfile -maddrqual=ignore -xassembler-with-cpp -mwarn=-3 -Wa,-a -DXPRJ_default=default  -msummary=-psect,-class,+mem,-hex,-file  -ginhx032 -Wl,--data-init -mno-keep-startup -mno-osccal -mno-resetbits -mno-save-resetbits -mno-download -mno-stackcall   -std=c99 -gdwarf-3 -mstack=compiled:auto:auto     -o build/default/production/mcc_generated_files/pin_manager.p1 mcc_generated_files/pin_manager.c

"C:\Program Files\Microchip\xc8\v2.32\bin\xc8-cc.exe"  -mcpu=16F18346 -c   -mdfp="C:/Program Files/Microchip/MPLABX/v5.45/packs/Microchip/PIC16F1xxxx_DFP/1.5.133/xc8"  -fno-short-double -fno-short-float -O0 -fasmfile -maddrqual=ignore -xassembler-with-cpp -mwarn=-3 -Wa,-a -DXPRJ_default=default  -msummary=-psect,-class,+mem,-hex,-file  -ginhx032 -Wl,--data-init -mno-keep-startup -mno-osccal -mno-resetbits -mno-save-resetbits -mno-download -mno-stackcall   -std=c99 -gdwarf-3 -mstack=compiled:auto:auto     -o build/default/production/mcc_generated_files/TCPIPLibrary/rtcc.p1 mcc_generated_files/TCPIPLibrary/rtcc.c

"C:\Program Files\Microchip\xc8\v2.32\bin\xc8-cc.exe"  -mcpu=16F18346 -c   -mdfp="C:/Program Files/Microchip/MPLABX/v5.45/packs/Microchip/PIC16F1xxxx_DFP/1.5.133/xc8"  -fno-short-double -fno-short-float -O0 -fasmfile -maddrqual=ignore -xassembler-with-cpp -mwarn=-3 -Wa,-a -DXPRJ_default=default  -msummary=-psect,-class,+mem,-hex,-file  -ginhx032 -Wl,--data-init -mno-keep-startup -mno-osccal -mno-resetbits -mno-save-resetbits -mno-download -mno-stackcall   -std=c99 -gdwarf-3 -mstack=compiled:auto:auto     -o build/default/production/mcc_generated_files/TCPIPLibrary/log.p1 mcc_generated_files/TCPIPLibrary/log.c

"C:\Program Files\Microchip\xc8\v2.32\bin\xc8-cc.exe"  -mcpu=16F18346 -c   -mdfp="C:/Program Files/Microchip/MPLABX/v5.45/packs/Microchip/PIC16F1xxxx_DFP/1.5.133/xc8"  -fno-short-double -fno-short-float -O0 -fasmfile -maddrqual=ignore -xassembler-with-cpp -mwarn=-3 -Wa,-a -DXPRJ_default=default  -msummary=-psect,-class,+mem,-hex,-file  -ginhx032 -Wl,--data-init -mno-keep-startup -mno-osccal -mno-resetbits -mno-save-resetbits -mno-download -mno-stackcall   -std=c99 -gdwarf-3 -mstack=compiled:auto:auto     -o build/default/production/mcc_generated_files/tmr1.p1 mcc_generated_files/tmr1.c

"C:\Program Files\Microchip\xc8\v2.32\bin\xc8-cc.exe"  -mcpu=16F18346 -c   -mdfp="C:/Program Files/Microchip/MPLABX/v5.45/packs/Microchip/PIC16F1xxxx_DFP/1.5.133/xc8"  -fno-short-double -fno-short-float -O0 -fasmfile -maddrqual=ignore -xassembler-with-cpp -mwarn=-3 -Wa,-a -DXPRJ_default=default  -msummary=-psect,-class,+mem,-hex,-file  -ginhx032 -Wl,--data-init -mno-keep-startup -mno-osccal -mno-resetbits -mno-save-resetbits -mno-download -mno-stackcall   -std=c99 -gdwarf-3 -mstack=compiled:auto:auto     -o build/default/production/mcc_generated_files/TCPIPLibrary/network.p1 mcc_generated_files/TCPIPLibrary/network.c

"C:\Program Files\Microchip\xc8\v2.32\bin\xc8-cc.exe"  -mcpu=16F18346 -c   -mdfp="C:/Program Files/Microchip/MPLABX/v5.45/packs/Microchip/PIC16F1xxxx_DFP/1.5.133/xc8"  -fno-short-double -fno-short-float -O0 -fasmfile -maddrqual=ignore -xassembler-with-cpp -mwarn=-3 -Wa,-a -DXPRJ_default=default  -msummary=-psect,-class,+mem,-hex,-file  -ginhx032 -Wl,--data-init -mno-keep-startup -mno-osccal -mno-resetbits -mno-save-resetbits -mno-download -mno-stackcall   -std=c99 -gdwarf-3 -mstack=compiled:auto:auto     -o build/default/production/mcc_generated_files/interrupt_manager.p1 mcc_generated_files/interrupt_manager.c

"C:\Program Files\Microchip\xc8\v2.32\bin\xc8-cc.exe"  -mcpu=16F18346 -c   -mdfp="C:/Program Files/Microchip/MPLABX/v5.45/packs/Microchip/PIC16F1xxxx_DFP/1.5.133/xc8"  -fno-short-double -fno-short-float -O0 -fasmfile -maddrqual=ignore -xassembler-with-cpp -mwarn=-3 -Wa,-a -DXPRJ_default=default  -msummary=-psect,-class,+mem,-hex,-file  -ginhx032 -Wl,--data-init -mno-keep-startup -mno-osccal -mno-resetbits -mno-save-resetbits -mno-download -mno-stackcall   -std=c99 -gdwarf-3 -mstack=compiled:auto:auto     -o build/default/production/mcc_generated_files/spi1.p1 mcc_generated_files/spi1.c
mcc_generated_files/TCPIPLibrary/log.c:112:14: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned int' to 'uint8_t' (aka 'unsigned char') [-Wconversion]
    priVal = LOG_MAKEPRI(facility, severity);
           ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
mcc_generated_files/TCPIPLibrary/log.c:59:45: note: expanded from macro 'LOG_MAKEPRI'
#define LOG_MAKEPRI(fac, pri)   (((fac) << 3) | (pri))
                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~

1 warning generated.
mcc_generated_files/TCPIPLibrary/rtcc.c:29:2: warning: USING TIMER1 FOR TIMEBASE [-W#warnings]
#warning USING TIMER1 FOR TIMEBASE
 ^

1 warning generated.

"C:\Program Files\Microchip\xc8\v2.32\bin\xc8-cc.exe"  -mcpu=16F18346 -c   -mdfp="C:/Program Files/Microchip/MPLABX/v5.45/packs/Microchip/PIC16F1xxxx_DFP/1.5.133/xc8"  -fno-short-double -fno-short-float -O0 -fasmfile -maddrqual=ignore -xassembler-with-cpp -mwarn=-3 -Wa,-a -DXPRJ_default=default  -msummary=-psect,-class,+mem,-hex,-file  -ginhx032 -Wl,--data-init -mno-keep-startup -mno-osccal -mno-resetbits -mno-save-resetbits -mno-download -mno-stackcall   -std=c99 -gdwarf-3 -mstack=compiled:auto:auto     -o build/default/production/mcc_generated_files/TCPIPLibrary/lfsr.p1 mcc_generated_files/TCPIPLibrary/lfsr.c

"C:\Program Files\Microchip\xc8\v2.32\bin\xc8-cc.exe"  -mcpu=16F18346 -c   -mdfp="C:/Program Files/Microchip/MPLABX/v5.45/packs/Microchip/PIC16F1xxxx_DFP/1.5.133/xc8"  -fno-short-double -fno-short-float -O0 -fasmfile -maddrqual=ignore -xassembler-with-cpp -mwarn=-3 -Wa,-a -DXPRJ_default=default  -msummary=-psect,-class,+mem,-hex,-file  -ginhx032 -Wl,--data-init -mno-keep-startup -mno-osccal -mno-resetbits -mno-save-resetbits -mno-download -mno-stackcall   -std=c99 -gdwarf-3 -mstack=compiled:auto:auto     -o build/default/production/mcc_generated_files/TCPIPLibrary/tcpv4.p1 mcc_generated_files/TCPIPLibrary/tcpv4.c

"C:\Program Files\Microchip\xc8\v2.32\bin\xc8-cc.exe"  -mcpu=16F18346 -c   -mdfp="C:/Program Files/Microchip/MPLABX/v5.45/packs/Microchip/PIC16F1xxxx_DFP/1.5.133/xc8"  -fno-short-double -fno-short-float -O0 -fasmfile -maddrqual=ignore -xassembler-with-cpp -mwarn=-3 -Wa,-a -DXPRJ_default=default  -msummary=-psect,-class,+mem,-hex,-file  -ginhx032 -Wl,--data-init -mno-keep-startup -mno-osccal -mno-resetbits -mno-save-resetbits -mno-download -mno-stackcall   -std=c99 -gdwarf-3 -mstack=compiled:auto:auto     -o build/default/production/main.p1 main.c

"C:\Program Files\Microchip\xc8\v2.32\bin\xc8-cc.exe"  -mcpu=16F18346 -c   -mdfp="C:/Program Files/Microchip/MPLABX/v5.45/packs/Microchip/PIC16F1xxxx_DFP/1.5.133/xc8"  -fno-short-double -fno-short-float -O0 -fasmfile -maddrqual=ignore -xassembler-with-cpp -mwarn=-3 -Wa,-a -DXPRJ_default=default  -msummary=-psect,-class,+mem,-hex,-file  -ginhx032 -Wl,--data-init -mno-keep-startup -mno-osccal -mno-resetbits -mno-save-resetbits -mno-download -mno-stackcall   -std=c99 -gdwarf-3 -mstack=compiled:auto:auto     -o build/default/production/mcc_generated_files/TCPIPLibrary/ip_database.p1 mcc_generated_files/TCPIPLibrary/ip_database.c
mcc_generated_files/TCPIPLibrary/ipv4.c:103:12: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'uint32_t' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'uint16_t' (aka 'unsigned short') [-Wconversion]
    return cksm;
    ~~~~~~ ^~~~
1 warning generated.

"C:\Program Files\Microchip\xc8\v2.32\bin\xc8-cc.exe"  -mcpu=16F18346 -c   -mdfp="C:/Program Files/Microchip/MPLABX/v5.45/packs/Microchip/PIC16F1xxxx_DFP/1.5.133/xc8"  -fno-short-double -fno-short-float -O0 -fasmfile -maddrqual=ignore -xassembler-with-cpp -mwarn=-3 -Wa,-a -DXPRJ_default=default  -msummary=-psect,-class,+mem,-hex,-file  -ginhx032 -Wl,--data-init -mno-keep-startup -mno-osccal -mno-resetbits -mno-save-resetbits -mno-download -mno-stackcall   -std=c99 -gdwarf-3 -mstack=compiled:auto:auto     -o build/default/production/mcc_generated_files/TCPIPLibrary/arpv4.p1 mcc_generated_files/TCPIPLibrary/arpv4.c

"C:\Program Files\Microchip\xc8\v2.32\bin\xc8-cc.exe"  -mcpu=16F18346 -c   -mdfp="C:/Program Files/Microchip/MPLABX/v5.45/packs/Microchip/PIC16F1xxxx_DFP/1.5.133/xc8"  -fno-short-double -fno-short-float -O0 -fasmfile -maddrqual=ignore -xassembler-with-cpp -mwarn=-3 -Wa,-a -DXPRJ_default=default  -msummary=-psect,-class,+mem,-hex,-file  -ginhx032 -Wl,--data-init -mno-keep-startup -mno-osccal -mno-resetbits -mno-save-resetbits -mno-download -mno-stackcall   -std=c99 -gdwarf-3 -mstack=compiled:auto:auto     -o build/default/production/mcc_generated_files/drivers/spi_master.p1 mcc_generated_files/drivers/spi_master.c
mcc_generated_files/TCPIPLibrary/tcpv4.c:949:74: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'uint16_t' (aka 'unsigned short') [-Wconversion]
                                    notAckBytes = currentTCB->localSeqno - tcpHeader.ackNumber;
                                                ~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

"C:\Program Files\Microchip\xc8\v2.32\bin\xc8-cc.exe"  -mcpu=16F18346 -c   -mdfp="C:/Program Files/Microchip/MPLABX/v5.45/packs/Microchip/PIC16F1xxxx_DFP/1.5.133/xc8"  -fno-short-double -fno-short-float -O0 -fasmfile -maddrqual=ignore -xassembler-with-cpp -mwarn=-3 -Wa,-a -DXPRJ_default=default  -msummary=-psect,-class,+mem,-hex,-file  -ginhx032 -Wl,--data-init -mno-keep-startup -mno-osccal -mno-resetbits -mno-save-resetbits -mno-download -mno-stackcall   -std=c99 -gdwarf-3 -mstack=compiled:auto:auto     -o build/default/production/mcc_generated_files/device_config.p1 mcc_generated_files/device_config.c
1 warning generated.

mcc_generated_files/TCPIPLibrary/ip_database.c:52:34: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'uint16_t' (aka 'unsigned short') to 'uint8_t' (aka 'unsigned char') [-Wconversion]
       ((uint8_t *)&ip_addr)[x]= (uint16_t)atoi((const char*)pch); //jira: CAE_MCU8-5647
                               ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

1 warning generated.

"C:\Program Files\Microchip\xc8\v2.32\bin\xc8-cc.exe"  -mcpu=16F18346 -c   -mdfp="C:/Program Files/Microchip/MPLABX/v5.45/packs/Microchip/PIC16F1xxxx_DFP/1.5.133/xc8"  -fno-short-double -fno-short-float -O0 -fasmfile -maddrqual=ignore -xassembler-with-cpp -mwarn=-3 -Wa,-a -DXPRJ_default=default  -msummary=-psect,-class,+mem,-hex,-file  -ginhx032 -Wl,--data-init -mno-keep-startup -mno-osccal -mno-resetbits -mno-save-resetbits -mno-download -mno-stackcall   -std=c99 -gdwarf-3 -mstack=compiled:auto:auto     -o build/default/production/mcc_generated_files/TCPIPLibrary/mac_address.p1 mcc_generated_files/TCPIPLibrary/mac_address.c

"C:\Program Files\Microchip\xc8\v2.32\bin\xc8-cc.exe"  -mcpu=16F18346 -c   -mdfp="C:/Program Files/Microchip/MPLABX/v5.45/packs/Microchip/PIC16F1xxxx_DFP/1.5.133/xc8"  -fno-short-double -fno-short-float -O0 -fasmfile -maddrqual=ignore -xassembler-with-cpp -mwarn=-3 -Wa,-a -DXPRJ_default=default  -msummary=-psect,-class,+mem,-hex,-file  -ginhx032 -Wl,--data-init -mno-keep-startup -mno-osccal -mno-resetbits -mno-save-resetbits -mno-download -mno-stackcall   -std=c99 -gdwarf-3 -mstack=compiled:auto:auto     -o build/default/production/mcc_generated_files/mcc.p1 mcc_generated_files/mcc.c

"C:\Program Files\Microchip\xc8\v2.32\bin\xc8-cc.exe"  -mcpu=16F18346 -c   -mdfp="C:/Program Files/Microchip/MPLABX/v5.45/packs/Microchip/PIC16F1xxxx_DFP/1.5.133/xc8"  -fno-short-double -fno-short-float -O0 -fasmfile -maddrqual=ignore -xassembler-with-cpp -mwarn=-3 -Wa,-a -DXPRJ_default=default  -msummary=-psect,-class,+mem,-hex,-file  -ginhx032 -Wl,--data-init -mno-keep-startup -mno-osccal -mno-resetbits -mno-save-resetbits -mno-download -mno-stackcall   -std=c99 -gdwarf-3 -mstack=compiled:auto:auto     -o build/default/production/mcc_generated_files/TCPIPLibrary/ENC28J60.p1 mcc_generated_files/TCPIPLibrary/ENC28J60.c

"C:\Program Files\Microchip\xc8\v2.32\bin\xc8-cc.exe"  -mcpu=16F18346 -c   -mdfp="C:/Program Files/Microchip/MPLABX/v5.45/packs/Microchip/PIC16F1xxxx_DFP/1.5.133/xc8"  -fno-short-double -fno-short-float -O0 -fasmfile -maddrqual=ignore -xassembler-with-cpp -mwarn=-3 -Wa,-a -DXPRJ_default=default  -msummary=-psect,-class,+mem,-hex,-file  -ginhx032 -Wl,--data-init -mno-keep-startup -mno-osccal -mno-resetbits -mno-save-resetbits -mno-download -mno-stackcall   -std=c99 -gdwarf-3 -mstack=compiled:auto:auto     -o build/default/production/mcc_generated_files/TCPIPLibrary/icmp.p1 mcc_generated_files/TCPIPLibrary/icmp.c

"C:\Program Files\Microchip\xc8\v2.32\bin\xc8-cc.exe"  -mcpu=16F18346 -c   -mdfp="C:/Program Files/Microchip/MPLABX/v5.45/packs/Microchip/PIC16F1xxxx_DFP/1.5.133/xc8"  -fno-short-double -fno-short-float -O0 -fasmfile -maddrqual=ignore -xassembler-with-cpp -mwarn=-3 -Wa,-a -DXPRJ_default=default  -msummary=-psect,-class,+mem,-hex,-file  -ginhx032 -Wl,--data-init -mno-keep-startup -mno-osccal -mno-resetbits -mno-save-resetbits -mno-download -mno-stackcall   -std=c99 -gdwarf-3 -mstack=compiled:auto:auto     -o build/default/production/mcc_generated_files/TCPIPLibrary/log_syslog.p1 mcc_generated_files/TCPIPLibrary/log_syslog.c

"C:\Program Files\Microchip\xc8\v2.32\bin\xc8-cc.exe"  -mcpu=16F18346 -c   -mdfp="C:/Program Files/Microchip/MPLABX/v5.45/packs/Microchip/PIC16F1xxxx_DFP/1.5.133/xc8"  -fno-short-double -fno-short-float -O0 -fasmfile -maddrqual=ignore -xassembler-with-cpp -mwarn=-3 -Wa,-a -DXPRJ_default=default  -msummary=-psect,-class,+mem,-hex,-file  -ginhx032 -Wl,--data-init -mno-keep-startup -mno-osccal -mno-resetbits -mno-save-resetbits -mno-download -mno-stackcall   -std=c99 -gdwarf-3 -mstack=compiled:auto:auto     -o build/default/production/mcc_generated_files/TCPIPLibrary/log_console.p1 mcc_generated_files/TCPIPLibrary/log_console.c
mcc_generated_files/TCPIPLibrary/log_syslog.c:51:10: fatal error: 'udpv4.h' file not found
#include "udpv4.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
(908) exit status = 1
nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:419: recipe for target 'build/default/production/mcc_generated_files/TCPIPLibrary/log_syslog.p1' failed

make[2]: *** [build/default/production/mcc_generated_files/TCPIPLibrary/log_syslog.p1] Error 1

make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
mcc_generated_files/TCPIPLibrary/ENC28J60.c:678:24: warning: implicit conversion changes signedness: 'int' to 'uint16_t' (aka 'unsigned short') [-Wsign-conversion]
    b = ETH_SPI_READ8()<< 8;
      ~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
mcc_generated_files/TCPIPLibrary/ENC28J60.c:749:20: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'uint16_t' (aka 'unsigned short') to 'uint8_t' (aka 'unsigned char') [-Wconversion]
    ETH_SPI_WRITE8(data);
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
mcc_generated_files/TCPIPLibrary/ENC28J60.c:57:45: note: expanded from macro 'ETH_SPI_WRITE8'
#define ETH_SPI_WRITE8(a) SPI1_ExchangeByte(a)
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
mcc_generated_files/TCPIPLibrary/ENC28J60.c:763:25: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'uint32_t' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'uint8_t' (aka 'unsigned char') [-Wconversion]
    ETH_SPI_WRITE8(data >> 16);
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
mcc_generated_files/TCPIPLibrary/ENC28J60.c:57:45: note: expanded from macro 'ETH_SPI_WRITE8'
#define ETH_SPI_WRITE8(a) SPI1_ExchangeByte(a)
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
mcc_generated_files/TCPIPLibrary/ENC28J60.c:764:25: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'uint32_t' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'uint8_t' (aka 'unsigned char') [-Wconversion]
    ETH_SPI_WRITE8(data >> 8);
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
mcc_generated_files/TCPIPLibrary/ENC28J60.c:57:45: note: expanded from macro 'ETH_SPI_WRITE8'
#define ETH_SPI_WRITE8(a) SPI1_ExchangeByte(a)
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
mcc_generated_files/TCPIPLibrary/ENC28J60.c:765:20: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'uint32_t' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'uint8_t' (aka 'unsigned char') [-Wconversion]
    ETH_SPI_WRITE8(data);
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
mcc_generated_files/TCPIPLibrary/ENC28J60.c:57:45: note: expanded from macro 'ETH_SPI_WRITE8'
#define ETH_SPI_WRITE8(a) SPI1_ExchangeByte(a)
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
mcc_generated_files/TCPIPLibrary/ENC28J60.c:898:9: warning: implicit conversion changes signedness: 'int' to 'unsigned int' [-Wsign-conversion]
        ClearBit( pHead->flags, ETH_TX_QUEUED);         // txQueued = false
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
mcc_generated_files/TCPIPLibrary/ENC28J60.c:94:68: note: expanded from macro 'ClearBit'
#define ClearBit( bitField, bitMask )   do{ bitField = bitField & (~bitMask); } while(0)
                                                                ~  ^~~~~~~~
mcc_generated_files/TCPIPLibrary/ENC28J60.c:936:5: warning: implicit conversion changes signedness: 'int' to 'unsigned int' [-Wsign-conversion]
    ClearBit( pHead->flags, ETH_WRITE_IN_PROGRESS);     // writeInProgress = false
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
mcc_generated_files/TCPIPLibrary/ENC28J60.c:94:68: note: expanded from macro 'ClearBit'
#define ClearBit( bitField, bitMask )   do{ bitField = bitField & (~bitMask); } while(0)
                                                                ~  ^~~~~~~~
mcc_generated_files/TCPIPLibrary/ENC28J60.c:1207:45: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'uint16_t' (aka 'unsigned short') [-Wconversion]
    return (uint16_t)((cksm & 0xFF00) >> 8) | ((cksm & 0x00FF) << 8);
    ~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
8 warnings generated.
make[2]: Leaving directory 'D:/videos/mchip/enc28j60/enc28j60_app1.X'
nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:91: recipe for target '.build-conf' failed

make[1]: Leaving directory 'D:/videos/mchip/enc28j60/enc28j60_app1.X'
nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: recipe for target '.build-impl' failed

make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
 
BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 10s)
```

Comment: The compiler can't find the #include file. Help it find the file.

Comment: Make sure that you have the complete TCP/IP stack source code properly downloaded into a local folder on your PC. Search in there for the `udpv4.h` file - take note of which directory you find it in. Check you C project's list of include directories and make sure that the directory you found the file in is present in the list.